# Python - Print multiple colors in one line

Tags: python, python-3.x, output

I'm new to programming, so keep this in mind as you read my post, as I probably made a dumb mistake that I didn't realize. Basically, I was attempting to print the word "Rainbow," except that the R is red, the a is yellow, the i is green, etc. However, the following code I used to attempt to produce this output an error.

```
from termcolor import cprint
cprint("R", 'red' + "a", 'yellow', "i", 'green' + "n", 'blue' + "b", 'cyan' + "o", 'magenta' + "w", 'grey')
```

Error:

```
TypeError: cprint() takes from 1 to 4 positional arguments but 9 were given
```

My question is how can I produce my wanted output? Thanks in advance.

Comment: "An error" is the worst of all errors since nobody can help you with that.

Comment: what is the error you see?

Comment: **Welcome to SO.** Please get familiar with [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) it's the 4 commandments of asking a question here. In there it states: "It doesn't work" is not a problem statement. Tell us what the expected behavior should be. Tell us what the exact wording of the error message is, and which line of code is producing it. Please [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55074520/edit) your question with the error message so we can help you!

Answer (score 4):

You are probably searching for  `colored` function in `termcolor` module.

```
from termcolor import colored
print(colored("R", 'red') ,colored( "a", 'yellow'),colored( "i", 'green' ),colored( "n", 'blue'),colored( "b", 'cyan' ),colored("o", 'magenta'),colored( "w", 'grey'))
```

This will print each of the letter as the color you mentioned.

Comment: You might possibly to prefer to access such functions via termcolor2. https://pypi.org/project/termcolor2/ For example, PyCharm will autocomplete some identifiers for you.